# Error file heroku-php-apache2 : using apachectl instead of httpd in ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, heroku

I'm trying to run locally the app from "Getting Started with PHP on Heroku" manual. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I had to change "httpd" command in "heroku-php-apache2" file by apachectl to continue. But finally I get this fail:

```
Action '-D NO_DETACH -c Include /home/{{user}}/php-getting-started/vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/apache2/heroku.conf' failed.
17:58:40 web.1  | The Apache error log may have more information.
17:58:40 web.1  | Process exited unexpectedly: httpd
```

The line is ( sleep 2; httpd -D NO_DETACH -c "Include $httpd_config" || true; echo "httpd" >&3; ) 3> $wait_pipe &

I just change httpd by apache2ctl.

Any workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't find the error log with additional information. The command looks valid. Could this be related to the apache configuration?